# Java REST Web Services in NetBeans 14 not creating WADL file

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I am trying to learn REST web services using Java. I am using NetBeans 14 and just trying to do a basic restful web service. The issue I keep getting is it pops up with the error Cannot Access WADL file. It's not being generated by the IDE. I have looked for it. I've tried everything, but have been unable to get it to generate. I am using GlassFish server.

Has anyone had any problems similar to this one? I could really use some help or point me in the right direction. I've been working on this for a few days with no luck.

I have tried reading through the libraries to see if I missed one I should have loaded. I have tried rebuilding the restful web services.

Comment: Please add the error log to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.